# SQLAlchemy pushes the same default id on creation

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have this method to create a random user id:

```
import random
import string

def generate_id():
    size = 9
    chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

And this SQLAlchemy object for a user:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True, default=generate_id())
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    # ...
```

My problem is: sometimes it works well (some people manage to sign up and create a new user without any trouble) and sometimes the generated `default` for `user.id` has already been used, triggering this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: user.id
```

This error happens at least half of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `generate_id` function in the model definition. This means that only the first time your application starts a value will be generated (once for each thread/server).

Since SQLAlchemy accepts callable defaults you can simply remove the `()` so it automatically gets called internally:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True, default=generate_id)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    # ...
```

Comment: Yeah! Makes lot of sense. Didn't know about the callable default! You made my day :)